# Powershell script to get only Hour and Minute from NET TIME command

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, time, ob-get-contents

I am trying to retrieve only the Date and Time from the PowerShell script, Below is what I have tried till now:

Script:

```
NET TIME \\ComputerName | Out-File $location

(Get-Content $location)  | % {
    if ($_ -match "2018 : (.*)") {
        $name = $matches[1]
        echo $name
    }
}
```

`net time` output is as below:

```
Current time at \\Computer Name is 1/3/2018 1:05:51 PM

Local time (GMT-07:00) at \\Computer Name is 1/3/2018 11:05:51 AM

The command completed successfully.
```

I only need the part in local time "11:05".

Comment: Why do you need to do it? Aren't your computers synchronizing their clocks with a nearby domain controller?

Comment: I need this to execute another command "Dumplog" which only takes begin time and end time as parameters.

Command  : dumplog ctisvr /bt "Local time" /m "CSTAUniversalFailureConfEvent"

Hence i need local time of the server to run for last 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -match to test a regex
Then check the matches with autogenerated $matches array

```
PS> "Current time at \Computer Name is 1/3/2018 1:05:51 PM Local time (GMT-07:00) at \Computer Name is 1/3/2018 11:05:51 AM" -match '(\d\d:\d\d):'
True
PS> $matches
Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              11:05
0                              11:05:

PS> $matches[1]
11:05
```

Answer (score 2):

Although `Get-Date` doesn't support querying remote computers, the date/time and timezone information from a remote computer can be retrieved using WMI; an example can be found at [this TechNet PowerShell Gallery page](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-DateTime-and-Time-Zone-b0f43d4c). Using the `Win32_LocalTime` class, adjusted based on the `Win32_TimeZone` class, will provide the information in a form that is easily converted into a `[DateTime]` for further use in your script.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this may not work for you if you do not have PowerShell remoting enabled, but if it is I would do it this way.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName ComputerName -ScriptBlock {(Get-Date).ToShortTimeString()}
```

Comment: This one did not work, it gives the time but not the local time of the server. :(

Comment: I should have tested more, but all of my machines are in one time zone. I modified the answer to convert the time to a string on the remote machine instead and now it should work.

Comment: Is there anyway to display the result in 24 Hr Format ?

Comment: `"{0:HH:mm}" -f [datetime] $x` used this one. now it works

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

You can use this function to get whatever information you want. I adapted the code from [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-DateTime-and-Time-Zone-b0f43d4c). It converts the `LocalDateTime` value obtained using `Get-WmiObject` into a `DateTime` object. You can do whatever you want with the date information thereafter. You can also adapt this to use whichever DateTime variable you want (i.e. last boot time).

---

### Code

```
function Get-RemoteDate {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$True,
            ValueFromPipeLine=$True,
            ValueFromPipeLineByPropertyName=$True,
            HelpMessage="ComputerName or IP Address to query via WMI"
        )]
        [string[]]$ComputerName
    )
    foreach($computer in $ComputerName) {
        $timeZone=Get-WmiObject -Class win32_timezone -ComputerName $computer
        $localTime=([wmi]"").ConvertToDateTime((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer).LocalDateTime)
        $output=[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            'ComputerName'=$computer;
            'TimeZone'=$timeZone.Caption;
            'Year'=$localTime.Year;
            'Month'=$localTime.Month;
            'Day'=$localTime.Day;
            'Hour'=$localTime.Hour;
            'Minute'=$localTime.Minute;
            'Seconds'=$localTime.Second;
        }
        Write-Output $output
    }
}
```

Call the function using either of the following methods. The first is for a single computer and the second for multiple computers.

```
Get-RemoteDate "ComputerName"
Get-RemoteDate @("ComputerName1", "ComputerName2")
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this for my multiple computers list.

Comment: @prashanthtv the second call does exactly that. It takes a string array and loops over it